# Displaying child page content of a certain parent

Tags: loop, child-pages

What I would like to do is to create a WP loop that will display info from a child page of an adult page ID, so the Page ID is 2. I would like to pick a page ID to display what page.

So that way I could display information from another child page on an alternative page.

Owen

Comment: Please, add [research efforts](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) to your Question. Search the Codex for `is_page`, `get_post` and `get_posts`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a near duplicate of a number of questions here, but the "single random result" might make it somewhat distinct.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'page',
    'post_parent'       => $post->ID,                               
    'orderby'           => 'rand',
    'posts_per_page'    => 1,
    'no_found_rows'     => true
);
$child = new WP_Query($args);
var_dump($child->posts);
```

You are telling [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to pick 1) pages, 2) with the parent of the current page, 3) ordered randomly, 4) one result, and 5) don't bother tracking found rows since we already know it should be 0 or 1.

There are numerous examples of creating multiple loops here and in the Codex. You should be able to find plenty of information to flesh this out. In short you want:

```
while ($child->have_posts()) {
  $child->the_post();
  var_dump($post); // raw dump of your child post
}
```