# Page naming when there is a sub-category only sometimes.

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

I need help with understanding page naming to display a sub-category which only occurs only sometimes. I also need to understand if I need to create a custom Taxonomy to achieve this? I am using CPT UI plugin.

I have a CPT, called APPLES.

All of my main apple parent types are displaying as images on archive-apple.php. (maybe this should be page?). I will then click on the image of the parent apple type I want to know more about and I will see a sub-page of images/information about that specific kind of Apple.

BUT, 
Sometimes that individual Apple parent will have two or three variations of the main parent Apple. So an intermediary page with two sub-type images must display giving me the choice of what sub-type I want to see.

Here is a diagram to explain what I am trying to do. Please and thank you for any help.

[image]

Comment: You probably need something like: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/83124/displaying-child-page-content-of-a-certain-parent/83126?s=3|1.9979#83126 Or: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/102668/display-child-pages-on-a-parent-and-child-page-using-featured-thumbnails/102678?s=5|1.8964#102678 Or: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/106544/wp-list-pages-show-pages-immediately-1-level-below-current-level/106553?s=9|0.6612#106553

Comment: Thanks, I will see if I can get where I need to go with these.

Comment: u should use `archive-apples.php` instead of `archive-apple.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do u mean by:

> Page naming

?? If you are after a way to implement this situation, then here you go:

You have 2 options:

**1st Option**

Use

```
'hierarchical'                  => false
```

while registering your `apples` post type, using `register_post_type`. Then, you will have the option to put apples posts, as parents and children, using the post edit page.

**2nd Option**:

Use

```
function add_apples_cat_taxonomy(){
    register_taxonomy(
        'apples_category',
        'apples',
        array(
            'label' => __( 'Apples category' ),
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'apples_cat' ),
            'hierarchical' => true
        )
    );
}

add_action( 'init', 'add_apples_cat_taxonomy' );
```

to add an `post_type` dependent taxonomy named `apples_category`, and use it to expand the desired hirearchy.